# MATLAB read a desired number of matrices from a cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell

I have the following cell array

`C_Array` `<5000x1>`

And inside `C_Array` I have
`<ix2 single>`    where `i = a changing integer`

I only want to look at the first `2000` matrices in my cell array.

My attempt has been

```
for j = 1:2000
     My_Desired_Range = C_Array{j,:}
end
```

But this just gives me the matrix for `{2000,1}` so how do I produce a cell array with just the matrices ranging from `{1,1}` to `{2000,1}` ?

Comment: Okay so now matrix 2000 has been indexed into a cell array, great. But only the 2000th matrix not the other 1999?

Comment: Can't you just use `My_Desired_Range = C_Array(1:2000,:)`?

Comment: Yep, oops.... (Palm to face)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply as mentioned in the comments by @Wauzl

My_Desired_Range = C_Array(1:2000,:)